# Helm template - install multiple package/release from external charts available from Internet

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, to-be-continuous

I am a new comer in [to-be-continuous helm template](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/helm). I would like to know if helm template is able to install multiple package/release from external charts available from Internet with customized values in local value.yml files ?

As with GitLab CI template for Kubernetes, is there a way to choose from either template-based deployment or scrip-based deployment ?

Moreover, any example about helm template usage is highly appreciate since no example are available at https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/samples.

Have a good day.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may perfectly deploy a Helm chart from the internet by setting the following variables:

- `HELM_DEPLOY_CHART`: the chart name,
- `HELM_REPOS` (optional): if you're using chart(s) from other repositories than default ones (Helm stable & bitnami).

You may also perfectly use values files per environment. For example set `HELM_STAGING_VALUES` to define your values file for the staging environment.

If you need to deploy more than one chart, you should probably use [parallel matrix jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs)